# Need information about mso style

Tags: css, ms-office

I need to know what options or properties can be set in msWord using the MSO styles besides the limited css styles, I already found that information but nothing else.

For example I run across mso-add-space:auto and have no clue what this really does or what it can be set for, percent, pixels, etc etc.

I have been scouring the Internet for something similar to the w3cschools list of css properties with no luck.

Any sort of info or direction to search would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are proprietary codes internal to MS Office. You should never allows these codes to be included as part of a web site. This content should be stripped down to plain text, and re-coded using proper HTML + CSS mark-up.

A second effect of using MS Office content is that special characters are usually encoded as Windows-1251, not the unicode standard UTF-8. This will cause broken characters in your layout.

Comment: Long story and not a choice, but I am importing an html doc into MSWord and having problems keeping the formatting the same.

Comment: Trying to keep MS Word formatting is futile. It will never work. There is no replacement for hand-coding in this type of document. If formatting is important, consider using a PDF instead.